# How to copy only a particular range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have to design a function in Excel VBA which takes a source row number in *sheet1* and destination row number in *sheet2* as input arguments. But the columns which have to be copied are the same in both rows, i.e. from column 1 to column 20.

I have tried like this:

```
Function CopyRow(ByVal rowA, ByVal rowB)
    Rows(rowA).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Rows(rowB).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
End Function
```

But it is copying the entire row. Give me an alternate and simple way to do this?

Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: quick question. why do yo need to use `Function` instead of a `Private Sub`. Based on your code, it fits a `Sub` more that a `Function`. Is there any special reason?

Comment: @L42, you should have stated it harder- there is no reason to use `Function` in this situation, it should be a `sub` for sure! It doesn't matter that code will work when called in IDE but it doesn't return any value.

Comment: @KazJaw sure thing. :) I was just trying to get more info to gauge the posters level of understanding so we can explain it better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is copying the whole row because `Rows(rowA).Select` is selecting the entire `rowA`

I agree with the earlier comments that it's better suited to a `Sub` than a `Function` because there is no return value. `Functions` shouldn't be used when you are trying to change something on a sheet - someone may type `=Co` and see your `CopyRow` as an available `Function`. It won't work - if you enter the `Function` on a sheet it will return 0 and not do the copy/paste.

This will do it without selecting any sheets or ranges and should be much faster.

```
Function CopySht1RowAtoSht2RowB(rowA, rowB)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(rowA, 1).Address, Cells(rowA, 20).Address).Copy _
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(rowB, 1).Address, Cells(rowB, 20).Address)
End Function
```

You can call it from other procedures, in this case `Sub Wrapper()` using

```
Sub Wrapper()
    Call CopySht1RowAtoSht2RowB(1, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  `Range("A" & rowA & ":T" & rowA).Select`